# Tkinter & Pycharm console not working consistenly

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

Tkinter & Pycharm console do not work consistenly when it comes to setting up a label's size. Here is a sample code that shows the error :

```
## Imports
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as font
import pylab

## Main
def test():
    root = tk.Tk()
    label = tk.Label(master = root, text = "test 1", bg = "lightblue", bd = 5, font = font.Font(size = 15))
    label.pack(side = "top", fill = "x")
    label = tk.Label(master = root, text = "test 2", bg = "lightblue", bd = 5, font = font.Font(size = 10))
    label.pack(side = "top", fill = "x")
    root.mainloop()

# test()
```

If i launch the function test from the console i don't have the same result as if i launch it from the code itself. Which is a bit weird.
Here are screenshots summing up the problem.
[image: console] (test() is launched from the console)
[image: code] (test() is launched from the code)

The solution in this post [Python modules clashing (tkinter & pylab) leading to weird inconsistency in Pycharm Python console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69616589/python-modules-clashing-tkinter-pylab-leading-to-weird-inconsistency-in-pych/69661695#) did not work (i assume this little trick works for tk.PhotoImage but not for tk.Label).
I could not reproduce the error on Pyzo which is why I assume PyCharm is the problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you for reading me

Comment: Update : tested on a Linux laptop and Windows 11 laptop - didn't get the error on Linux but got it on Windows 11.

Comment: updates like that should be put into the question (you can [edit] it), I got the same issue when running on Windows 8.1, couldn't figure out why tho